# How to I solve this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the assignment ive been given and im having trouble making it work properly. But it says that im having an error in the last line at "print(total)" - but im not sure what is wrong here. Does someone know the answer to this ?

Change the code below to create a function that calculates the cost of a trip. It should take the miles, milesPerGallon, and pricePerGallon as parameters and should return the cost of the trip.

```
miles = 500
milesPerGallon = 26
numGallons = miles / milesPerGallon
pricePerGallon = 3.45
total = numGallons * pricePerGallon
print(total)
```

The code ive come to so far is this :

```
def costOfTrip(miles,milesPerGallon,pricePerGallon):
    miles = 500
    milesPerGallon = 26
    numGallons = miles / milesPerGallon
    pricePerGallon = 3.45
    total = numGallons * pricePerGallon
    print(total)
```

Comment: *What* error? Give a [mre] including the traceback, or contrasting the actual output with what you expected.

Comment: When I run it, I simply just get the output : 

<function costOfTrip>

But it should calculate and return the cost of the trip.

Comment: Then I'd guess you're doing `print(costOfTrip)`, not actually *calling* `costOfTrip(...)`.

Comment: Well the program should calculate the cost of the trip with the function, 

but i cant make it calculate it properly. 

It simply does not give the total cost

Comment: Once you're actually calling it you'll realise you're immediately shadowing the parameters, so it always gives the same output. That makes it not very useful as a function!

Answer (score 2):

depends on where you're writing the code, it may be `print total`. But just swap out the print for a return, so it would be lie:

```py
return total
```

Also, you're always assigning 500 to miles, 26 to imlesPerGallon and 3.45 to pricePerGallon. Try this out:

```py
def costOfTrip(miles,milesPerGallon,pricePerGallon=3.45):
    numGallons = miles / milesPerGallon
    total = numGallons * pricePerGallon
    return total
```

This means that you have to pass in the `miles`, `milesPerGallon` and the `pricePerGallon` parameters. The `pricePerGallon` is optional and defaults to `3.45`. You can then call the function like this:

```py
total = costOfTrip(500,26)
print(total)
```

Comment: If I put in 

    return total 

it just give no output at all

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look like:

```py
def costOfTrip(miles, milesPerGallon, pricePerGallon):
    # miles, milesPerGallon and pricePerGallon are received args 
    numGallons = miles / milesPerGallon
    total = numGallons * pricePerGallon
    return total
```

### Usage example

```py
cost = costOfTrip(500, 26, 3.45)
print(cost)
```

Comment: None of the above suggestions solve the question sadly :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the values as arguments to function to get the values calculated and returned. you can refer below code.

```py
def costOfTrip(miles,milesPerGallon,pricePerGallon):
    numGallons = miles / milesPerGallon
    total = numGallons * pricePerGallon
    return total

miles = 500
milesPerGallon = 26
pricePerGallon = 3.45

print(costOfTrip(miles,milesPerGallon,pricePerGallon))
```

**Output**

```
66.34615384615385
```